# Only display dynamically created table rows with certain value

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table

First I will show what I currently have so the question will (hopefully) be clear.

I have a SQL query to get data from my DB which looks like this:

```
$strSQL1        = "SELECT Klant.ID, Klant.Naam, Klant.Email, Klant.Soort, Subscriptions.Klant_ID, Subscriptions.Status, Subscriptions.Datum, Subscriptions.ID
                  FROM NAW.Klant 
                  JOIN NAW.Subscriptions 
                  ON Klant.ID = Subscriptions.Klant_ID,
                  (SELECT MAX(Subscriptions.ID) as ids, Klant_ID 
                  FROM NAW.Subscriptions
                  WHERE Mail_ID ='".$_GET["ID"]."'  
                  GROUP BY Klant_ID) table2
                  WHERE Subscriptions.ID=table2.ids"; 
$objQuery1      = mysql_query($strSQL1);
```

Then I add the data in a HTML table which looks like this:

```
<table width="700" border="1">  
<tr> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">ID  </div></th>  
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Naam  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Email  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Soort  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Status  </div></th> 
   <th width="91"> <div align="center">Datum  </div></th> 
</tr> 
<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) : ?> 
<tr>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Klant_ID"];?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Naam"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Email"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Soort"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Status"];?> </div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Datum"];?> </div></td>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

The table currently displays this data:

[image]
(These are all made up names/emails)

My question is if there is a way to display only the rows where 'Status' is 10? It is probably possible using an 'if' statement but I can't figure out how to do this. If anyone knows how to do this or push me in the right direction it would be great. Thanks in advance!

NOTE:
I know I shouldn't be using mysql_* but since I will change to PDO later on so you guys don't have to mention that^^

NOTE #2:
I forgot to add that I wish not to change my SQL query because it will mess up the data I get from the DB. (I know this is kinda vague but I don't know how to explain it otherwise)

Comment: just add `AND \`Subscriptions.Status\` = 10` to `WHERE Subscriptions.ID=table2.ids`

Comment: looks like a correct answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) :
    if($objResult1["Status"]!= 10) continue;
?>
```

Comment: This worked, ty^^ I will accept this as the answer when I can.

Comment: Np, but note, if you will not use other rows then better to check in SQL (like in other two answers).

Answer (score 0):

add to your WHERE clause the condition you wish to enforce.

```
"SELECT Klant.ID, Klant.Naam, Klant.Email, Klant.Soort, Subscriptions.Klant_ID, Subscriptions.Status, Subscriptions.Datum, Subscriptions.ID
                  FROM NAW.Klant 
                  JOIN NAW.Subscriptions 
                  ON Klant.ID = Subscriptions.Klant_ID,
                  (SELECT MAX(Subscriptions.ID) as ids, Klant_ID 
                  FROM NAW.Subscriptions
                  WHERE Mail_ID ='".$_GET["ID"]."'  
                  GROUP BY Klant_ID) table2
                  WHERE Subscriptions.ID=table2.ids
                  AND Subscriptions.Status = 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `Subscriptions.Status = 10` in your where clause of query

```
$strSQL1        = "SELECT Klant.ID, Klant.Naam, Klant.Email, Klant.Soort, Subscriptions.Klant_ID, Subscriptions.Status, Subscriptions.Datum, Subscriptions.ID
                  FROM NAW.Klant 
                  JOIN NAW.Subscriptions 
                  ON Klant.ID = Subscriptions.Klant_ID,
                  (SELECT MAX(Subscriptions.ID) as ids, Klant_ID 
                  FROM NAW.Subscriptions
                  WHERE Mail_ID ='".$_GET["ID"]."'  
                  GROUP BY Klant_ID) table2
                  WHERE Subscriptions.ID=table2.ids AND Subscriptions.Status = 10"; 
$objQuery1      = mysql_query($strSQL1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) :
if($objResult1p['Status'] == 10){
?>
<tr>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Klant_ID"];?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Naam"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Email"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Soort"];?> </div></td> 
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Status"];?> </div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Datum"];?> </div></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
endfor;
?>
```